# Finding the rate of decrease but ignoring increases over time with PromQL

Tags: grafana, promql

I'm using Prometheus to record the %-level in a liquid tank over time. The metric is captured as a gauge using Grok. When the tank gets to a certain level, we fill it again (roughly weekly), but a change in the rate at which the tank empties can be indicative of errors in our system.

Therefore, I would like to calculate a some-what accurate rate of %-loss over time for different time periods, for example 3, 10, 30, & 60 days, so I can see if the rate is changing on my Grafana dashboard and then create some relevant alerts. An example dataset is in the image below, and I'd basically like to calculate the gradients indicated by the arrows for the different time periods.

[image: example data set (Tank % over time)]

Is this possible with PromQL or grafana? Will the filling periods (increases) cause problems, or can these be ignored somehow?

Thank for your help and advice! :)

EDIT:

I've just discovered the deriv() function. This seems to generally do the trick but it can't manage the fills/resets. Is there a trick to deal with those changes, ignoring a positive-change to only consider the negative rates?

Thanks!

Comment: "ignoring a positive-change to only consider the negative rates?" you can simply use `<0`. Something like `deriv(my_metric[1d]) <0`

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this!
One further point: If I'm using a query like this:
deriv(my_metric[7d]) <0
Then a positive change during one day kills my metric. Is there a way to ignore any >0 days during a deriv range?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will calculate the average decline rate in the last week, assuming your sample rate is 1 per minute.

```
avg_over_time(
  (
    deriv(level[60s:]) < 0
  )[1w:60s]
) / 60
```

Breakdown:

- `deriv(level[60s:])`: in each point in time, the current level minus the level one minute ago
- `deriv(...) < 0`: only the values where the value mentioned above is negative
- `avg_over_time(...[1w:60s])`: the average of all the recorded negative values in the last week
- `... / 60`: since the values we calculated are equal to the level decline *per sample* (60 seconds), we divide the result by the sample duration in seconds to get the level decline *per second*

Note: the result might be slightly lower than the real decline rate, since some of the samples represent a time period in which the level both decreased and increased (the edges in the graph). The higher you sample rate is relatively to the level change rate, the more accurate your results will be. Your could also get rid of the edges in other ways but I'm guessing that in your case it will not be an issue.